# File path autocomplete not working when i writing sass file in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellicode

File path autocomplete working wrong when I'm writing sass file in VS Code .....
Don't show path, but show other CSS property value
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Path Intellisense extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense).

I also suggest you to install [SCSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-scss)

Comment: SCSS IntelliSense seems quiet useless. Even when adding `scss.showErrors`  - as they say - it does not solve the problem. Strange extension ...

Answer (score 0):

use quotation marks and scroll further down in the suggested ones.

```
background: url("../")
```

need install https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete